# Fetch user account or email address in MS Access Web app

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I would like to fetch the users email or O365 account into an Access Web App.  This is to record the user who did the row entry.  I've tried the UserEmailAddress() function on a list view Textbox, but can't seem to get it to work.
Would appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you use a macro to do it. You can get the current user and then write it into a field.